# Java Interface Query

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

If we execute run the following code, the output is 10.

---

```
interface X{
 int abc = 0;
}
interface XX extends X{
 int abc = 10;
}
class XTest implements XX
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  System.out.println("Hello World! --> " +abc);
 }
}
```

---

But as per Java, interface variables are public static final. but how am I getting 10 as output?

Answer (score 6):

This code works as it should.

Your XTest class implements XX, so it gets the value of `abc` from the public static final instance in that interface.

XX shadows X, so it supercedes the `abc` value from X.

Comment: Thanks duffymo,

does shadows means override?
If yes, we can't overrides public static final variables right?

can you please give some more clarification? Or any pointers to any article?

Comment: It's not exactly "overiding".  This might clarify: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html

Comment: 'Shadows' means more like replaces and hides than overrides but the effect is similar in this case.  The abc in XX replaces and hides the abc in X.  The abc in X is still there though. Classes that implement XX would have to refer to X.abc to see the 0 value.

Comment: Thank you very much Skip Head & duffymo its really helps.